# Filtering child html element from parent

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get the inner element of the container with .filter(). But it return undefined until searching it within parent element with .find(); How can I search it directly with .filter() only without the need to use .find() ?

So the output will like this : `<p class="para">This Paragraph Contents</p>`

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let $htmlEl = `
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                       <div class="body-content">
                           <p class="para">This Paragraph Contents</p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            `;
  let $res = $($htmlEl);
  let $parentHtml = $res.filter('.container').html();
  let $childHtml = $res.filter('.body-content').html();
  // alert($res.filter('.container').find('.body-content').html());
  // alert($parentHtml);
  console.log($childHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I suggest you re-read what [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) does.  This question is like saying: I'm trying to do `1-1=2` but it's giving me 0, if I use `+` it works, but I want to use `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter works on a selection

Instead you can use a selector and scope it, I guess that is the same as find, but why is find not allowed?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let $htmlEl = `<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="body-content">
        <p class="para">This Paragraph Contents</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>`;
  
  let $res = $($htmlEl);
  $("body").append($res)
  let $childHtml = $('.body-content',$res).html().trim()
  console.log($childHtml);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mlungjan. I don't want to append items each, I though before that filter will search the matched item. I think I will use find find() after filtering because it works fine. Thank you